# Creating new visual studio project from taskbar pin?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have pinned my devenv.exe to the taskbar from this location:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE

When I right click the icon in the taskbar I see Pinned solutions, Recent solutions, a horizontal rule, then "Unpin this program from the taskbar". I used to see "Visual Studio 2013" just above that unpin option.

Note: I recently right clicked "Visual Studio 2013" and chose unpin by accident. How can I get it back? I can't right click and start a new project from the pinned exe anymore. Ugghhh.

Comment: Find it in menu or metro screen and drag-n-drop or right click to pin. Actual procedure depends on OS version. Also it seems unrelated to StackOverflow.

Comment: Can't drag and drop, I try putting the devenv.exe back onto the pinned icon and I get the red no symbol

Comment: Better way to phrase question may be "how to add shortcut to devenv.exe to Visual Studio task bar icon's jump list"

Comment: Forget about devenv, unpin it and pin Visual Studio shortcut from Start menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this using Drop's comment. I had to unpin it, then pin it to the task bar using the start menu shortcut.